# python matplotlib pcolor blank space

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to implement a contour map using matplotlib's pcolor function, however, there appears to be some subtle rules relating to grid arrangement to ensure a fully covered figure.

To illustrate:

```
a = arange(0., .8+.16, .16)
b = arange(0., .5+.10, .10)
A, B = meshgrid(a, b)
Z = A + B
pcolor(A,B,Z)
```

This returns the figure
[image]

despite `shape(A)` = `shape(B)` = 6. So my question is simply: what is affecting the white space on the right of the figure and how can I remove it? Thanks.

Comment: You might also do better with `a = np.linspace(0, 0.8, 6, endpoint=True)`

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is a result of rounding in floating point numbers. The closest number to 0.8 that can be represented as a Python float is 0.80000000000000004. Matplotlib then rounds up to its idea of the next "nice" number at which to place an axis tick mark. You can control this behavior either by setting the axis limits explicitly:

```
xlim(0, 0.8)
```

or telling Matplotlib to fit your data exactly instead of setting the limits to round numbers:

```
axis('tight')
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do it for `contourf` ?